# Explain the comparison in this small C program

Tags: c

What will be the output of the following C code? 
Can the `int` data type take the floating-point values?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  float a = 1.1;
  int b = 1.1;

  if(a==b)
     printf("YES");
  else
     printf("NO");
}
```

Comment: No... `int` can't take `float` so there is a different data-type `float`

Comment: Int can only store whole numbers (...,-2,-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...). If you assign a float to an int, everything behind the period will just be cut off and will be lost. `2.9 = 2`   and `-2.9 = -2`

Answer (score 2):

The output will be  **NO**

It's because `int` can't store `float` values correctly. So, the value stored in `b` will be `1` which is not equal to `1.1`. So, the `if` case will never be satisfied and thus the output will be NO always.

Answer (score 1):

The value stored in `b` will be `1`. When comparing, `b` will be cast to the `float` value `1.0f`, so the comparison will yield NO.

Answer (score 1):

> int b = 1.1;

This truncates the double value `1.1` to `1` before assigning to variable `b`. The output therefore is `NO`.

But you can compare `int` to `float`. Consider this example:

```
float a=1.0;
int b=1;

if(a==b)
    printf("YES");
else
    printf("NO");
```

Here, `a` is converted to `float` before the comparison, and therefore you would get a `YES` output.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the answer No when you execute it.

That's because when

```
int b=1.1;
```

was executed, it initialized a variable `b` and then assigned the `int` of `1.1` that is `1`.  You can check this by outputting the value of `b`.

Also the type `int` stores whole numbers only but `float` can store fractional numbers. The types are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

It will compile without any errors. The output of the program will be "NO".

In C, `int` and `float` are 2 different data types. Even when you try to assign the value 1.1 to an integer variable in C, it will be initialized as 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Others already told you that the answer will be **NO.** Can the int data type take the floating-point values?

Yes they can, but only in one statement! IIf you want int variable to behave like float variable you need to cast it to float.

For example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 3;
printf("%f \n", (float)x/y);
```

Output will be 5.0/3 and that would be float value. `(float)x` is called casting. You can also cast float value into integer, `(int)some_var` etc.

**Note:** *Type of x and y will remain int*! They only behave like float in this statement. 
However, in your program that won't work, because as soon as you declare `int b = 1.1;` b becomes 1.